# Terraform error: "Provider doesn't support resource: gsuite_group_settings"

Tags: terraform, google-workspace

I am trying to update the Gsuite-group settings for the first time.

Here's a piece of code I'm using in my Terraform script:

[image]
[image]

The results are:

[image]

Why am I getting this error?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello, instead of providing screenshots, it is usually better to paste the code snippet in your question along with the error you're getting. This allows others to quickly attempt in reproducing the issue and provides easier readability. Consider editing your question to satisfy these. More on this [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/9146820).

Comment: What version of the provider are you using? What is the output of `terraform -v`?

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full `terraform -v` output from your project as it includes the provider versions as well. The group settings resource for that provider was added in 0.1.22: https://github.com/DeviaVir/terraform-provider-gsuite/releases/tag/v0.1.22

Comment: Thank you Andy Shinn. 

Yes, it's issue with the gsuite provider version . Currently it is pointing to 0.1.19. I will go with the 0.1.22.

Comment: @Andy Shinn . As Mahesh confirmed that it seems the solution you provided resolved the case issue. Can you post this comment as answer?

Answer (score 1):

Perusing the releases for https://github.com/DeviaVir/terraform-provider-gsuite it looks like the `gsuite_group_settings` resource was added in 0.1.22: https://github.com/DeviaVir/terraform-provider-gsuite/releases/tag/v0.1.22.

I think this case may be that the provider version is out of date. Try upgrading to 0.1.22 or later.